# my upload file doesn't save the pdf extension in the upload folder but saves the name in the database. it only saves images in the upload folder

Tags: php

I have a page for uploading files. now my upload codes only upload image files but not the pdf files. even though the files names saves in the databse but the only the images save in the upload folder but the pdf doesn't.

here is my upload code:

```
$file_name_pass = $_FILES['passport_pic']['name'];
              $image_temp_name = $_FILES['passport_pic']['tmp_name'];
              $image_type = $_FILES['passport_pic']['type'];
              $image_extention = strtolower(substr($file_name_pass, strpos($file_name_pass, '.')+1));
if (($image_extention=='jpeg' || $image_extention =='jpg' || $image_extention =='pdf' || $image_extention=='png')&&($image_type == 'image/jpeg' || $image_type == 'image/png')) {
$location5 = "Uploads/".basename($_FILES['passport_pic']['name']);
               move_uploaded_file($_FILES['passport_pic']['tmp_name'], $location5);
```

}

Comment: please write the code you tried to solve your problem

Comment: A better explanation of the issue may be useful too, hard to tell what bit is actually wrong.

Comment: `&&($image_type == 'image/jpeg' || $image_type == 'image/png')` – and you expect that to be true, when the uploaded file was a PDF …?

Comment: just posted the code

Comment: Misorude please i tried using type pdf but didnt work. please can you help me with a better way of doing it ?

Comment: The type wouldn't be just `pdf` it would probably be `application/pdf`, but you can `var_dump($_FILES)` and see for yourself to confirm.

Answer (score 0):

for example just allow just to images

```
$image_type = $_FILES['passport_pic']['type'];

$allowedType=['image/png','image/jpeg'];

if(in_array($image_type,$allowedType)
{

   doUpload()
   saveToDb()
}
```